# Calculate duration based the same field between two documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have many collections. I have especially two types of collections:1. collections corresponding to the begin of the visualization of content in e-learning plateforme; 2. collections corresponding to the endof the visualization of this content. Here exemple of begin and end visualization collection:

Begin visualization:

```
    "statement" : {
    "actor" : {
        "objectType" : "Agent",
        "name" : "exemple1@gmail.com",
        "mbox" : "mailto:exemple1@gmail.com"
    },
    "verb" : {
        "id" : "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/launched",
        "display" : {
            "en" : "Launching the next piece of learning content",
        }
    },
    "object" : {
        "objectType" : "Activity",
        "id" : "https://exemple1.com/activities/plannode=5857",
        "definition" : {
            "name" : {
                "en" : "calculs",
            },
            "type" : "http://id.tincanapi.com/activitytype/legacy-learning-standar"
        }
    },
    "context" : {
        "platform" : "exemple",
        "language" : "en",
    },
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-16T23:45:06+01:00",
    "id" : "0d7c852d-f1bf-45be-8a25-aff286bf1c30",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
},
```

End visualization:

```
        "statement" : {
    "actor" : {
        "objectType" : "Agent",
        "name" : "exemple1@gmail.com",
        "mbox" : "mailto:exemple1@gmail.com"
    },
    "verb" : {
        "id" : "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/terminated",
        "display" : {
            "en" : "Launching the next piece of learning content",
        }
    },
    "object" : {
        "objectType" : "Activity",
        "id" : "https://exemple1.com/activities/plannode=5857",
        "definition" : {
            "name" : {
                "en" : "calculs",
            },
            "type" : "http://id.tincanapi.com/activitytype/legacy-learning-standar"
        }
    },
    "context" : {
        "platform" : "exemple",
        "language" : "en",
    },
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-16T23:45:06+01:00",
    "id" : "0d7c852d-f1bf-45be-8a25-aff286bf1c30",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
},
```

Now, what I want to do is to group theses collection by `object.id` and calculate the duration of the content visualization = timestamp (content end visualization) - timestamp (content begin visualization).

I try the following code but it does not work:

```
db.statements.aggregate([
{$match:{'statement.verb.id':{"$in":["http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/launched", "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/terminated"]}}]},
{$group:{_id:{
        objectid: "$statement.object.id",
        learner: "$statement.actor.mbox"
        },
        duration : {$subtract: ["$timestamp", "$timestamp"}]}}
       }
     }
```

])

Can any help me to calculate duration between theses two collections (duration need to be caculated based on two fields having the same name :timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.statements.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"statement.verb.id":{"$in":["http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/launched","http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/terminated"]}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"objectid":"$statement.object.id","learner":"$statement.actor.mbox"},
    "first":{"$first":"$timestamp"},"second":{"$last":"$timestamp"}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"duration":{"$abs":{"$subtract":["$first","$second"]}}}}
])
```